# android and ms access

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ms-access, cloud

Am developing an android web application which have to access an database in the cloud or internet.
so in the cloud am using ms-access as my database

please help me with some tutorials or code samples to connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

uri u = Uri.parse(websiteText.getText().toString());

i.setData(u);

try {
    startActivity(i);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(PassEdit.this, R.string.invalid_website, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consier building a 100% web based with Access.

New for Access 2010 is the ability to create web based applications. You can then publish that application and forms to SharePoint or even the low cost office 365 (starts at $6 per month, and you can hang more then one user off that account).

You then just have the phone hit the web site. I am doing that now with my windows 7 phone and the Access screens look like this:

[image]

and

[image]

(above is from the wp7 emulator, but they look identical on my phone).

All of the buttons, style etc. was built only using Access on my desktop. I then hit publish, and then the forms + code etc. goes up to the cloud.

Note that code you write in a Access form when published to the web is converted into JavaScript and that means code can run and do things in the form without making round trips to the server. There is no ActiveX or Silverlight required for these forms. In fact the forms are converted into .net XAML forms.

Take a quick look at the following short video of mine and note how at the half way point I switch to running the Access application in a browser.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

Thus these access applications run fine on my smartphone or in fact even on my iPad. So using the new web tools in Access 2010 would allow you consume the forms on any device, not just an android phone.